# The purpose of $ at end of a variable

Tags: angular

I'm just learning angular 2 and ran across the following:

```
public progress$ = this._progress.asObservable();
```

I'm curious as to what the '$' represents at the end of the 'progress' label.

Answer (score 16):

It's just a convention often used for observables that can be subscribed to and emit a stream of events to distinguish it from other members.